# To maximise the sum of absolute values

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Maximize sum of absolute value
[image]

If sum of squares of $n$ real numbers is $1$, find the maximum sum of absolute value of difference of them. $$|a_1-a_2| + |a_2-a_3| + \ldots+|a_{n-1}-a_n| + |a_n-a_1|$$

For $n=2$  . $ a^2 + b^2 =1 $ now maximum value of given expression would be $2\sqrt{2}$.

For $n=3$ . $ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 =1 $. By considering some cases I got maximum value of expression as $2\sqrt{2}$.
I believe answer would also be $2\sqrt{2}$ for general value of $n$ but I am unable to prove it.

Comment: Please, improve your formatting

Comment: The minimum of the sum of absolute values of the differences is obviously zero. e.g. $a_1= a_2=\ldots = a_4 = 1/2.$

Comment: Previous question: [To maximise the sum of absolute values](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4742867/89922).

Comment: The trick for determining if you have a maximum is to change each of the values by some small amount $(a_1 + h_1, a_2 + h_2, \dots, a_n + h_n)$, remembering that that new point must also satisfy the constraint that the some of the squares is $1$. Now work out if you can choose the $h_1, h_2,$ etc. in such a way as to make the sum of absolute values bigger. If so, then you have not found the maximum. If so, then you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $n$ is even we can achieve a value of $2\sqrt{n}$ by letting $a_{j} = (-1)^j/\sqrt{n}$.  This value is maximal.  To see this, let $c_j$ denote the coefficient of $a_j$ when the absolute difference sum is expanded.  The only possible values of $c_j$ are $-2$, $0$, and $2$.  Therefore$$
|a_1 - a_2| + |a_2 - a_3| + \cdots + |a_{n-1}-a_n| + |a_n - a_1| =\\
c_1 a_1+c_2 a_2 + \cdots +c_n a_n \le\\ 2n\frac{|a_1| + |a_2| + \cdots + |a_n|}{n} \le 2n \sqrt{\frac{a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \cdots a_n^2}{n}} = 2\sqrt{n}.
$$
The power-mean inequality was used in the second-to-last step.

When $n$ is odd we can achieve a value of $2\sqrt{n-1}$ by using the solution for $n-1$ together with $a_n = 0$.  This is maximal, and it cannot be achieved unless one of the $a_j$ is zero.  To see this, suppose all the $a_j$ are non-zero.  In this case there are an equal number of positive and negative $c_j$.  Therefore when $n$ is odd at least one of the $c_j$ is $0$.
Suppose it's $c_n = 0$ (w.l.o.g.).  Then$$
|a_1 - a_2| + |a_2 - a_3| + \cdots + |a_{n-1}-a_n| + |a_n - a_1| =\\
c_1 a_1+c_2 a_2 + \cdots +c_{n-1} a_{n-1} \le\\ 2(n-1)\frac{|a_1| + |a_2| + \cdots + |a_{n-1}|}{n-1} \le 2(n-1) \sqrt{\frac{a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \cdots a_{n-1}^2}{n-1}} = 2\sqrt{(n-1)(1-a_n^2)} < 2\sqrt{n-1}.
$$